# Adding Post Counts to Menu (Nav) Programmatically?

Tags: posts, wp-query, menus, navigation, walker

I'm fairly stumped on this.

Without getting too query-heavy, I was wondering what path one might take to produce a menu that links to a category of posts, and displays in parenthesis how many new posts there are.

Example:

**News (5 new)

Articles (8 new)**

...and so forth.

What is the most efficient way to achieve this without running a million queries?

Comment: What is the "new" which is appended? Do you (also) want to do some date/time diff-ing?

Comment: That is correct! Getting a count would be good, getting a date evaluation (new) would be better.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress' get_categories() function returns an array of category objects, each of which has a "count" property for the number of posts in that category.  So something like this would get you a list of links to category pages:

```
$categories = get_categories();

$markup = '<ul>';
foreach( $categories as $category ) {
   $catName = $category->category_nicename;
   $count   = $category->count;
   $url     = get_category_link( $category->cat_ID );

   $markup .= '<li>';
     $markup .= "<a href=\"{$url}\">{$catName} ({$count})</a>";
   $markup .= '</li>';
}
$markup .= '</ul>';
```

That would allow you to show a count using a single query.  I'm sure there is a way to find a count of "new" posts using a more complex custom query instead of get_categories(), but I'd probably just eat any extra overhead of making another query for each category as opposed to trying to do it all in a single query.  Call me lazy.

Answer (score 0):

If you call [`wp_list_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories), and add the parameter `'show_count'=> 1`, it will return the number of posts in each category, inside parentheses.

Regarding getting a date evaluation, you might want to use the [date parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters) in `WP_Query`.